# Convert Arduino fs:File* into c++ std::File*

Tags: c++, file, arduino, tinyxml2

it seemed too easy. I stored an xml file on a sdcard connected to my esp32.
I use the `SD.open()` function to access the files stored on the sdcard. For parsing the xml file I downloaded the tinyxml2 library and tried to use the `xmlDocument.LoadFile()` function.

The problem is that the `xmlDocument.LoadFile` function is using a `std::File` pointer. The `SD.open()` function return an `fs::File` pointer.

The resulting error message in my ArduinoIDE is:

> No matching function for call to `tinyxml2::XMLDocument::LoadFile(fs::File*)`.

Does anybody has an idea how to convert the `fs::File*` into `std::File*`?

Thank you very much!

tinyxml2 lib:[tinyxml2 lib](https://github.com/leethomason/tinyxml2)

Comment: Maybe, could be easier if you read using only SD.open() closing after read and instead of use the same descriptor (fs::File), create another descriptor (std::File) and write avoiding this problem.

Comment: Could you use `SD` to load the file into memory and then [tinyxml2::XMLDocument:Parse](https://leethomason.github.io/tinyxml2/classtinyxml2_1_1_x_m_l_document.html#af2b616169e6517182f6725f2498e9a01) to process the `XML` from there?

Comment: why xnl? can't you use JSON?

Comment: As @Galik mentioned I'll try to use the function Parse(const char*) to solve my problem.

Comment: @Juraj , you are right. First tinyXML2 isn't the best way to parse xml files on an esp32. SAX parser seem to be not that RAM hungry. JSON might be a better solution at all. But before changing all from xml to json, I will try to solve the problem. This is not an XML problem but a general problem i might have with other libraries.
Not easy if you are not familiar with c++ (or whatever arduino ide is offering)

Comment: I think it shouldn't be hard to write a std:File wrapper for fs::File

Comment: I ve never done this before. It will :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much.

as @Galik mentioned, his hint was the key for me. But in the long run @Juraj suggestion to use json the better way.